# Flex positionning in CSS

Tags: reactjs, css, react-native, flexbox

I'm creating a React Native application and I would like to use flex to structure the positionning of my elements on the screen. Considering that we have the following screen: the red zone got a `flex-grow` value of 1, the yellow zone 2 and the green zone 3. They all have a parent with a `display: flex` and `flex-grow: 1`. (This is React Native so default flex-direction is column).

**My question is the following**: What if there is no green zone? How could I tell flex to take 1/6 of the parent for the red zone, 2/6 for the yellow zone and leave the rest empty ?

[image]

Comment: please paste your CSS or make a codepen sample, this would be much better

Comment: Théo, do you want to do it only with flex or can you hear another suggestion?

Comment: @NicoDiz don't think react-native supports CSS grids at the moment...

Comment: because you don't have a *pseudo element* in react-native, you need an element for the green section to make this code work...

Comment: My solution could to to use https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid

Comment: Here is a demo on Expo @DucHong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the layout you described by applying `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex items. By setting the `flex-basis` to the appropriate percentages the layout holds up with or without the presence of the third div.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
}
.one {
  flex: 0 0 16.666%; /* dont grow, dont shrink, starting basis */
  background: red;
}
.two {
  flex: 0 0 33.333%; /* dont grow, dont shrink, starting basis */
  background: yellow;
}
.three {
  flex: 0 0 50%; /* dont grow, dont shrink, starting basis */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">ONE</div>
  <div class="two">TWO</div>
  <div class="three">THREE</div>
</div>
```

This time I omit the third div and we get the same layout:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
}
.one {
  flex: 0 0 16.666%; /* dont grow, dont shrink, starting basis */
  background: red;
}
.two {
  flex: 0 0 33.333%; /* dont grow, dont shrink, starting basis */
  background: yellow;
}
.three {
  flex: 0 0 50%; /* dont grow, dont shrink, starting basis */
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="one">ONE</div>
  <div class="two">TWO</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Théo, do you want to do it only with flex or can you hear another suggestion?

This is a perfect example to use [grid](https://cssreference.io/css-grid/).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h17tezLd/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="zone1"></div>
    <div class="zone2"></div>
    <div class="zone3"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .container {
        width: 150px;
        height: 300px;
        background: grey;
        display: grid;
        grid-template: 1fr 2fr 3fr / 100%;
        }
    .zone1 { background: red; }
    .zone2 { background: blue; }
    .zone3 { background: green; }
</style>
```

Comment: Could be an answer, I know that https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid exists in React Native to handle that possibility